# Mesibo - User not getting Online

Tags: java, android, flutter, mesibo

**The Problem I am facing** - When I try to hit the Mesibo API, I am able to get a token in response which is used to get the user online, but whenever I try to send a request to start Mesibo using the token I received, the online status shows "Not Connected" and it doesn't go online. Hence I won't be able to send any message or call anyone.

**What I have tried**- I have tried to use a sample app to make a user and get them online by using the same code. I am able to do so by using Mesibo's own servers. I have tried changing the app token and app id multiple times to check if the user goes online or not.

Alas no luck, can anyone please help me over here?

I have used [this](https://github.com/mesibo/samples/tree/master/android) as the sample app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting connection status 1, and instead getting 4 or 5, you are not creating a token for your app. The token must match the Android app id or iOS bundle id (for example, com.mesibo.xxx). If you are using Javascript API, ensure that you pass the same app id to the setAppName API call.

Also, ensure that you are NOT using the App Token. App Token must be secret and should only be used from the backend API. You MUST only use user token in your real-time API.

Read here https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/other/#i-am-not-getting-connection-status-1-online

Comment: what if the connection status is 2 @mesibo